# implement multiTouch with cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, touch

I have 2 buttons ,one uses for jumping (tap) and the other for walking (hold), they works perfect. the problem is that I can't use them in the same time. when I tap on jump button my sprite stop walking until I release the button and tap + hold it again.

I have searched in google but i didn't find any good tutorial for multiTouch, can anyone help me and show me examples to implement it? 
I have found that I need to use this line in the appDelegate:

```
[glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
```

but it still not working for me.
samples of my code:

```
self.isTouchEnabled = YES;


        -(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        for ( UITouch* touch in touches ) {

                UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
                CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

        if(CGRectContainsPoint(jumpBtn, location)) {...}

        }
      }
```

Comment: someone know better / another way?
Kirit's have a nice solution, but I am sure that there are better way to implement multiTouches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you set `[glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES]`in your Appdelegate

```
- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    NSArray *touchArray=[touches allObjects];

    if ([touchArray count] == 2)
      {
        //Double Click
      }
    else if([touchArray count]==1)
     {
       //Single Click
     }

}
```

Comment: this looks like a right solution, but I still have a issue with the multiTouch, I try put  
NSArray *touchArray=[touches allObjects];
    
    if ([touchArray count] > 2) {
        CCLOG(@"2 touches!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    } 
but it doesn't work for me. when it equal to 1 it works fine. I already put this line:
[glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
 in the appDelegate inside the - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
method and enable touch in my gameScene class. any suggestions?